# Keeping Form control Values after submit button if error comes

Tags: c#, winforms, submit-button

In winforms there are different controls like textbox,combobox dropdown. In these some fields are mandatory and some are not, so while validating all fields, if there is some error then it shows error and returns to that that method again, and all the control value gets clear. I want to keep those control value in form as such if error comes. How do I do this? Maybe I can check all control values not null, or something like this, but for not mandatory can't check this. How do I do it? Here is the code. I am displaying errors like this.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string title = txtTitle.Text;
            string fname = txtFirstName.Text;
            string mname = txtMiddleName.Text;
            string lname = txtLastName.Text;
            int feeAmount;

            if (txtTitle.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Title");
                return;
            }
            if (txtFirstName.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter First Name");
                return; 
            }
            if (fname.Length < 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Firstname must contain atleast 3 Character");
                return;
            }

            if (txtLastName.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Last Name");
                return;  
            }

if (rdoPercent.Checked == false && rdoPerPatnt.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Fee Unit");
                return; 
            }
if(db.NewDrMaster(title,fname,mname,lname,txtRegistrationNo.Text,txtSpeciality.Text, txtContact1.Text,landlineno,cmbCity.SelectedItem.ToString(),Address,txtPincode.Text,txtEmailID.Text,feeUnit,txtFee.Text,DrType,Display))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Doctor Refernced By added Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("failed");
            }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question could you please explain more?

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi to simply say If I get error "failed " than all the fields are getting cleared how do I keep them as such after this error message

Comment: Are you sure you are not manually clearing the fields?